# Spring JPA - Get all Child Elements

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have the following POJOs'

Filter ----> Filter Components

```
@Entity
public class Filter {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private int id;
            private String name;
    //Setters and getters are not shown
```

And I have the following child class

```
@Entity    
public class FilterComponents {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        private int component_id;
        private int component_type;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "filter_id")
        private Filter filter;
//Setters and getters are not shown
```

I created a repository to query for Filters

```
public interface FilterRepository extends JpaRepository <Filter, Long> {}
```

I am calling the `findAll()` function to get all Filters. The function is working fine; however, it only returns the name and id of each filter.

[image]

Is there a way to return the corresponding Filter Components as well? I assume I can write a join query, but I have a feeling that there is a cleaner way to do it!

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: @JB Nizet I tried the code. However, when  I called findAll() function. I am getting an infinite output (https://ibb.co/jqGGJd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Filter to FilterComponents a OneToMany unidirectional mapping. So, you will be managing child FilterComponents inside its parent.

```
@Entity
public class Filter {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private int id;
            private String name;
            @OneToMany
            @JoinColumn(name = "filter_id")
            private List<FilterComponents> filterComponenets;
}

@Entity    
public class FilterComponents {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        private int component_id;
        private int component_type;

        // Removed mapping 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably missing is a `filterComponents` field for a `Filter` e.g.

```
public class Filter {
  ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="cart")
  private List< FilterComponents> filterComponents;
```

You can define eager or lazy fetching depending on your needs here

Comment: Thank you.  When I implemented the code you suggested I get an infinite output https://ibb.co/jqGGJd

Answer (score 0):

Your `Filter` entity does not have any explicit association with `FilterComponent` entity. In this case you would need to do another request to select all filter components with the given filter id.

On the other hand you can declare the following field in the `Filter` entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "filter", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<FilterComponent> filterComponents;
```

and always load filter components eagerly.

If eager loading does not fit you you can use custom query with `left join fetch`:

```
select distinct f from Filter f left join fetch f.filterComponents c
```

Comment: Thank you. When added  "@OneToMany(mappedBy = "filter", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) private List<FilterComponent> filterComponents;" I got an infinite output https://ibb.co/jqGGJd !!

Comment: @DDSAMP Maybe it is caused by the way you mashal your entities to JSON. Your JSON marshaller tries to load `filter` field from `FilterComponent` entity and finally comes across the same `Filter` entity. Just ignore `filter` field during marshalling.

Comment: @ brianheart Thank you. I solved the issue by adding  "@jsonignore" to "@ManyToOne" to avoid JSON cycling